# I am not geting API response in react, using axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to display info from an API using axios and the hook useParams, it seems a straight foward exercise but it's not working. the API is working, here is the code:

```
// eslint-plugin-react-hooks
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { NavLink, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import styles from './CarDetails.module.css';
import Sidebar from '../../common/sidebar/Sidebar';

const CarDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [car, setCar] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .get(`https://carrental2.onrender.com/api/v1/cars/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setCar(response.data.car);
        console.log(response.data.car);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, [id]);

  const newLocal = <Sidebar />;
  if (loading) {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid vh-100 v-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <i className="fa-solid fa-spinner fa-spin fs-1" />
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <>
      {newLocal}
      <h2 className={styles.title}>CAR DETAILS</h2>
      <div className={styles.detailContainer}>
        <div className={styles.car}>
          <img src={car.image} alt={car.model} />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.detail}>
          <h2>{car.model}</h2>
          <div className={styles.carYear}>
            <p>year:</p>
            <p>{car.year}</p>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.price}>
            <p>Price Per Day: </p>
            <p className={styles.priceColor}>
              $
              {car.price}
            </p>
          </div>
          <NavLink to={`/reserve/${id}`} className={styles.btncontainer}>
            <button type="button" className={styles.reservebtn}>
              <i className="fa-solid fa-car-side me-3" />
              Reserve
            </button>
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default CarDetails;
```

I haven't tried a different approach as I believe this would be the simplest using Axios, where did I get it wrong? If you want to try the API link use cars 63 to 69.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I get an error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at companion-bubble.js:1465:19716
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Ln (companion-bubble.js:1465:19134)

Comment: I checked your response , and it have not car property.

Answer (score 1):

I checked axios api response , and it have not car property

please change useEffect to :

```
useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .get(`https://carrental2.onrender.com/api/v1/cars/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setCar(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, [id]);
```

[show result on code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-dream-fqzqhk?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: that did the trick, calling data.car was calling a property that does not exist, all I had to do was call the all data. thank you very much Abbas.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should sanity check `id`. Could be undefined if `useParams` is async. Secondly, you should add a catch to your axios promise to handle errors.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (id) {
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .get(`https://carrental2.onrender.com/api/v1/cars/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setCar(response.data.car);
        console.log(response.data.car);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }
}, [id]);
```

Comment: The suggestion to check `id` is nice. I don't think `useParams` can be `async`. But you attached the `catch` method on the state setter function, not the `Promise` returned by `axios`. Also, in this case, as the other answer mentioned, the problem was that the response body does not have a `car` property.

Comment: Oops! I fixed. Yeah I saw the other answer. Looks like that was it.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching from axios returns a *Promise< Response >* which means it must be **awaited**. useEffect doesn't support this, I use an async callback function to help use awaited functions inside of useEffect hooks.

```
// fetch data callback function vvv asyncronous
const fetchData = useCallback( async (id) => {
  setLoading(true);
  // await axios get function
  await axios
    .get(`https://carrental2.onrender.com/api/v1/cars/${id}`)
    .then((response) => {
      setCar(response.data);
      console.log(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
    });
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  
  // call the callback function
  fetchData(id);

        // include the function in the dependencies
}, [id, fetchData]);
```

Comment: It also works well, Gavin. The first suggestion by Abbas works without using the callback function. So, which of the two solutions is the best? and thank you very much for your feedback.